# Setting the visibility of User Profile Attribute to "Everyone" in online Sharepoint using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, user-profile-service

How to set the visibility of a user profile property to "Everyone" using PowerShell in SharePoint Online.

Tried below no luck.

```
$UserProfile.UserProfileProperties.Email["Visibility"] ="Everyone"
$UserProfile.UserProfileProperties.Email["Show me"] = "Everyone"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know it is **not** supported to set [User Profile policy settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262930(v=office.14).aspx) (such as *Default Privacy Setting* ) via SharePoint CSOM API, only [update user profile properties is supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/read-or-update-user-profile-properties-sample-app-for-sharepoint) via the following methods:

- `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager::SetSingleValueProfileProperty()`
- `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager::SetMultiValuedProfileProperty()`